# IE9 Support for HTML5 Canvas tag

Tags: html, canvas, internet-explorer-9

I am trying to test out the canvas tag, I started with this code:

```
<html>
 <canvas id="example" width="200" height="200">
    This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
 </canvas>
</html>
```

In IE8 I get the message:

```
 This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
```

I then installed IE9 but get the same error. Does IE9 support HTML5 canvas or not?

**Edit**

The problem was that I was missing the doctype tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: Is IE9 configured to act like IE8 so that it doesn't break existing web pages?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

IE9 does support canvas. [Here](http://9elements.com/io/projects/html5/canvas/) is an exmaple.

If canvas does not work in your browser, press F12 (open developer tools), and make sure, that IE is not in compatibility mode.

Comment: Thanks. This helped me a lot. Compatibility mode was my answer, it solved all my problems :)

Answer (score 12):

Extending the [answer from gor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016513/ie9-support-for-html5-canvas-tag/5016590#5016590), make sure that you have added following metadata.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
```

This will force IE to use the latest mode as possible and users don't need to change the compatibility mode from developer tools.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm aware HTML 5 Canvas support is under development for IE9, unless it is already in the RC.. Perhaps not the best website to find out you could browse to [html5test](http://html5test.com/) with IE9 to see if it supports certain HTML 5 tags or not. As an alternative you can browse to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com) which should also give you alot of info regarding the HTML5 support of browsers .

Answer (score 1):

Just an add on to this there's a little script I've been using called [excanvas](http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/) that has allowed me to run canvas animations (slowly) on IE8, haven't tried it on 7 and 6 but it's worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

If you install the Google Chrome Frame Plugin [http://www.google.com/chromeframe][1], it upgrades IE6-9 to run the webkit rendering engine - along with HTML5/CSS3 support.