# Why does my IE9 does not support canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, internet-explorer-9

[DiveIntoHTML5 Canvas](http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/canvas.html) claims that IE9 supports canvas.

However, when I tried doing canvas on IE9, it doesn't work:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'getContext'

I'm using IE9.0.8112.16421:

[image]

This is the code:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body style="background:black;margin:0;padding:0;">
<canvas id="canvas" style="background:white;width:100%;height:100%;">noob</canvas>
<script>
var img=new Image();
img.onload=function(){
  var c=document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
  var left,top;
  left=top=0;
  ctx.drawImage(img,left,top,20,20);
  var f=function(){
    left+=1;
    top+=1;
    c.width=c.width;
    ctx.drawImage(img,left,top,20,20);
  };
  setInterval(f,20);
};
img.src="http://a.wearehugh.com/dih5/aoc-h.png";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you try to get the canvas element?

Comment: http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Performance/FishIETank/Default.html If you see the fish, then Canvas works, you're just doing something wrong.

Comment: @tylermwashburn i do see the fish

Comment: Weird, only thing I see different from what I do is the closing of the canvas tag, try <canvas></canvas> total shot in the dark.. your code worked fine for me in jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/YQmky/

Comment: @Loktar i've closed it. nop its still not working. you using ie9.0.8112.16421?

Comment: @Dan what happened to the original site?

Comment: @Pacerier - (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108450/clean-up-on-aisle-dive-into-python-3)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Two things:

The `<canvas>` tag should having a corresponding closing tag `</canvas>`.  While some browsers will let you get by with just an opening tag, others (such as Firefox, and perhaps IE) won't.

In addition, IE9 requires you to declare an HTML5 doctype to use the canvas tag.  You can do this by placing `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of your code.

Comment: nice, yeah didn't want to post it as an answer because I couldn't technically test it to verify +1.

Comment: @Jeff i've closed it but its still not working. you using ie9.0.8112.16421?

Comment: Hmm peculiar, try including <!DOCTYPE html> at the top, ala http://stackoverflow.com/q/5016513/353278

Comment: Good eye. Never would've noticed. :)

Comment: Had same issue. One also need to check that IE9 is not in compatibility mode (broken page icon in the address bar)

Answer (score 14):

If IE9 is running in compatibility mode, the canvas tag will not be recognized, even if you are using the HTML5 DOCTYPE tag.  At least that has been my experience.

Check to see if IE9 is running in compatibility mode, which can be the case if the site is on an intranet.

Comment: if you additionally add <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge;chrome=1" > after the head tag IE will ALWAYS use the highest version of it's rendering modes. If it has the chrome plugin it uses that. Taken from Boilerplate HTML5.

Comment: Wow.  Yup, that solved it for me.  I was trying to display a HTML 5 page on my company's intranet site.  By turning off compatibility mode in Tools\Compatibility View Settings, finally, the HTML 5 page would get displayed.  Another ridiculous quirky setting from Microsoft !

Comment: One further problem: I actually wanted this page display in a WebView window in my C# app.  There, it continues to display the "Object doesn't support property or method 'getContext'" message.  How can I turn on this Compatibility hack in the WebView aswell ?

Answer (score 6):

`<!DOCTYPE html>` must be the first thing on your page. I had a script before the tag and it kept giving me the same error. This only happens in IE9, Chrome and Firefox work even with a script before the doctype tag.

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>` should ALWAYS be the first thing on your page, no matter which browser.

Answer (score 1):

Running IE 9.0.8112.16421. Canvas element won't work initially but if I hit F12 to bring up devtools, then refresh, it starts working. Normal refresh w/o devtools window open won't work. May be a JS init problem since the canvas was working before I moved the canvas drawing code into its own .js file. Works fine in Chrome/Firefox/Safari.

Answer (score 1):

when use IE10 in compatibility view please check IE compatibility version. Enter  F12 (open developer Tools) and check appropriate IE (for example IE9) version you need test and browser
will job right under this version.

Answer (score 0):

guys!

Check out Explorer Canvas on Google Code: 
https://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/

Hope this helps!

Tze

Comment: Is it 100% compatible?

Comment: Can't be sure...  I got IE11, and it seems to work in IE9-emulated.  If I end up installing native IE9, I'll let you know how it fares.